# Prevent Python from quitting on ctrl-D

Tags: command-line, python, readline

I find the following often happens to me:

1. I am using Python in an interactive terminal session
2. I accidentally type something with unbalanced parentheses
3. Python gives me a `...` prompt, expecting me to enter another line of code
4. In an attempt to get back to the Python command prompt, I instinctively type `ctrl-D` (end of transmission character)
5. Instead of exiting back to the `>>>` prompt, the Python process quits immediately, losing all the data from my interactive session

I would like this to not happen any more. Therefore my questions are:

- Is there a way to prevent Python from quitting when `ctrl-D` is pressed?;
- This might be wishful thinking, but is there any way I can make `ctrl-D` take me back to the Python prompt as I keep expecting it to do?

I use Python 3.6 installed with MacPorts on a Mac, but I guess this is a fairly platform-independent question. I believe this installation uses the Gnu Readline library for user interaction in case that's relevant.

Comment: I’m curious where your reflex to hit Ctrl-D came from here. In what program does it get you out of a sub-prompt like that without quitting? I think the “proper” solution is Ctrl-C, which will register as a KeyboardInterrupt exception and cancel the current prompt.

Comment: @DanielH I am actually not sure, but it probably mostly comes from bash.

Answer (score 1):

In basic programs which use 'cooked' mode, such as `cat`, <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is hooked at the tty layer as the *eof* character – it isn't sent to the process directly but generates an 'EOF' condition, causing the process to suddenly receive a 0-byte result from its `read(stdin)` call. (The process could just note the condition and continue though.)

In theory, because Python uses Readline, it isn't affected by this; it uses the terminal in 'cbreak' mode and lets Readline perform the handling of all special characters, including Ctrl+D. (That is, pressing the key will just return "\x04" from read, which is then handled internally by Readline bindings.)

*However,* Readline automatically binds the same control characters that it sees already bound on the tty layer, and has no option to control this from within Python. (Although it has an ~/.inputrc option, it seems to get ignored within Python.)

> is there a way to prevent Python from quitting when ctrl-D is pressed?;

So it seems that there is no way to stop Python's readline from handling Ctrl+D as EOF *unless* the tty layer has *eof* bound to something else (but not completely unbound). Your only option is to temporar redefine the EOF character to be something else than Ctrl+D at the tty layer (using `stty eof`), and redefine it to the correct value upon exit.

Try putting this in your $PYTHONSTARTUP file:

```
if True:
    import atexit, os
    os.system("stty eof ^X")
    atexit.register(lambda: os.system("stty eof ^D"))
```

(Note that completely undefinning `eof` won't work here – if Readline finds null, it will assume Ctrl+D by default.)

> Independently of the above, if I do type a mismatched parenthesis, what is the correct way to quit the `...` prompt and get back to the `>>>` one without running the code I've entered?

Press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>. Python accepts SIGINT to do this, as do most shells.

Comment: Python has the `readline` module. You could use it to bind ^D to a no-op in startup.